# How to use --harmony flag in my node app with phusion passenger?

Tags: node.js, passenger, ecmascript-harmony

Because our Node.js app need to run the service with koa.js, so the processes need to be started with `--harmony` flag.

Like this.

```
$ node --harmony app.js
```

But how can I configure the passenger to run the app with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by writing a wrapper script that executes the real node with --harmony, then instruct Passenger to use that wrapper script. For example, create /home/user/wrappers/node:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/node --harmony "$@"
```

Then:

```
chmod +x /home/user/wrappers/node
```

Passenger Standalone uses the first 'node' command in PATH, so you can do this:

```
export PATH=/home/user/wrappers:$PATH
cd /your-app
passenger start
```

If you use Passenger for Apache or Passenger for Nginx, set the appropriate directives:

```
# Apache
PassengerNodejs /home/user/wrappers/node

# Nginx
passenger_nodejs /home/user/wrappers/node;
```

Comment: Well I see, I have not read completely the passenger documentation. Thanks.

Comment: if you use Apache or Nginx, you could just write the command directly `passenger_nodejs 'node --harmony app.js';`

Comment: Adding flags to the `passenger_nodejs` directive didn't work for me, I had to use the wrapper as mentioned above.